# Sorting a dictionary by key, where the key is a mixture of string and number, then make a new dictionary with sorted key_values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary

```
dict1={'A_11':2,'A_10':5,'A_3':11,'A_2':6}
```

and I want to sort it by key and get

```
dict1_sorted={'A_2':6,'A_3':11,'A_10':5,'A_11':2}
```

I tried but I still got

```
{'A_10': 5, 'A_11': 2, 'A_2': 6, 'A_3': 11}.
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: `print( sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]) )` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.6+, dicts are ordered so you can do:

```
dict1={'A_11':2,'A_10':5,'A_3':11,'A_2':6}
def f(k):
    t = k.split('_')
    return t[0], int(t[1])
print({k: dict1[k] for k in sorted(dict1, key=f)})
```

This outputs:

```
{'A_2': 6, 'A_3': 11, 'A_10': 5, 'A_11': 2}
```

If you're using earlier Python version, you can substitute dicts with `collections.OrderedDict` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`dict` doesn't retain order unless you use python3.7. So use a `OrderedDict` instead

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dict1={'A_11':2,'A_10':5,'A_3':11,'A_2':6}
>>> OrderedDict({k:dict1[k] for k in sorted(dict1, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[-1]))})
OrderedDict([('A_2', 6), ('A_3', 11), ('A_10', 5), ('A_11', 2)])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sorted` with `lambda` in `key`

**Ex:**

```
dict1={'A_11':2,'A_10':5,'A_3':11,'A_2':6}
print( sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]) )
```

**Output:**

```
[('A_10', 5), ('A_11', 2), ('A_2', 6), ('A_3', 11)]
```

---

*or*

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dict1={'A_11':2,'A_10':5,'A_3':11,'A_2':6}
print( OrderedDict(sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are not orderable data structures. If you need order, you can use a different data type. I would propose the following:

```
dict1 = {'A_11':2,'A_10':5,'A_3':11,'A_2':6}

orderable = sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0].split('_')[-1]))
print(orderable)  # [('A_2', 6), ('A_3', 11), ('A_10', 5), ('A_11', 2)]
```

---

Also not that the ordering you are requesting is not the Python default for ordering strings. You seem to be interested in the ordering derived from the numbers contained in the string.